# Attach a single close button on the tabcontrol in C#

Tags: c#

How i can attach a single close button on the tabcontrol in C#.
There is a many way to attach a close button individually on each tabpages but I want to attach only single(e.g.) we can see on microsoft visual stdio 2008.
So Plz help me.

Comment: Are you looking for Visual studio like X button on tabheader, here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/firefoxtabcontrol.aspx)

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremath: From the question, "but I want to attach only single".  The article you referenced shows how to attach a button to each page.

Comment: @Merlyn, in the question eg we can see on microsoft visual studion 2008 tab. I didn't get the question correctly. I'm still not sure, so suggested the option I knew.

Comment: C# does not have a TabControl. WinForms. ASP.NET and WPF do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cheap way to do it, which might get you started:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TabItem Header="Test1" />
            <TabItem Header="Test2" />
            <TabItem Header="Test3" />
            <TabItem Focusable="False">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <Button Command="{Binding CloseTab}" Content="X" Width="21" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

You then are left to implement a `public ICommand CloseTab` field or property on your DataContext, and style the tab control to your liking.

[image: Close button in tab item header]

**Edit:**

If you use this method:

- Wiring up the button is tricky.  You have to be careful not to close the tab that contains the button
- This isn't well adapted to dynamically created tabs, because you have to ensure the close button is appended to the list
- You have to figure out how to re-select the last selected tab, when you close the selected tab
- You'll also have weird behavior when tabs start to wrap
- The tab-stop behavior is hard to get right.  You can't make the last `TabItem` focusable, since focus is used to determine what to close, but tabbing to the close button breaks the normal `TabItem` keyboard flow

I have come up with a style that makes the button look like a regular tab, with a bold **X** on it, which makes it visually more like IE8, and fixes the keyboard selection problem.  But it is complicated, and this solution is complicated enough.

Ultimately, a close button on every tab jives better with the tab control's default behavior.  The only problem with that solution is that it takes up more space.  You could cheat and make the close button collapse until you mouse over the tab item, though that's sort of a user-experience no-no, unless you just shrink it.

If you are serious about following through with the separate close button, I suggest you look at this article, and adapt what they do for the **scroll buttons** to your close button:

http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/10/TabControlStyling_PartThree.aspx

Ignore what they do for close buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to have your tabcontrol on another container control and let that control's close button do the job?